Android_studio_is_not_working
I just downloaded Android Studio but when I create new project my run button is not showing how to fix it now help me
Do i need to download jdk for it to work ?
Or is there another way to make it work?
Please help me make it work

Could you add a screenshot or error message!?

The run button requires a device to run the app on. Therefore you need to set-up and run an emulator instance or connect an ADB enabled phone e.g. via USB. But before you can run an app it first have to complete the Android Studio sync phase and then it has to be compiled. If Any of these two steps fail then of course you can not run the app.
